# How to customize SFTP verbose output in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am running a shell command with verbose to connect to remote host as below.

`sftp -v -oport = 22 $user@$host`

The above command is giving some debug notes and finally giving the enter password line like below.

```
`Password:`
```

How can I customize the above command line so that it shows as.

```
`$user@$host's Password:`
```

Please assist.

Comment: That's already the default for openssh. What software are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this out :

```
sftp -v -oport=22 $user@"$host" <<EOF
  echo -n "$user@$host's Password: "
  read -s password
  echo
  echo "$password"
  # your further commands here
EOF
```

Comment: This helps thanks I have another problem few remote server are just giving me Password: and few remote server are giving me $user@$host's Password:, when I run the same command. Could you please tell where to edit these details

Comment: Apologize for incomplete comment I have edited it.

Comment: @MohammedShaheer it means that the server is using a default prompt for password authentication and for the remote servers that display "$user@$host's Password:", it means that the server has been configured to display the username and hostname in the password prompt,the prompt is determined by the server's configuration and cannot be directly edited from the client-side command. It is up to the server administrator to customize the password prompt if needed.

Comment: Ok so you mean it has to be changed in remote server and if so should be customized in ssh_config file. Thanks for your assistant by the way.

Comment: yes you can modify the prompt by editing the SSH server configuration file, usually located at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. In this file, you can use the `PasswordAuthentication` option to control whether password authentication is allowed or not. Additionally, you can use the `Banner` option to specify a custom message or prompt to be displayed before the password prompt.